# SLA Calculation with PromQL

Tags: time-series, prometheus, victoriametrics

I have a time-series:

`sum(ALERTS{alertname="IngestionStopped", alertstate="firing"} unless on(table) (ALERTS{alertname="MyAlert1",alertstate="firing"} OR ALERTS{alertname="MyAlert2",alertstate="firing"}) OR vector(0))`

[image]

I do a `sum` because I have 1 TS for each partition of the table. I am interested even if a single partition has its ingestion stopped.

This TS = 0 when my service. is working fine. If it's > 0, it means there's something wrong with the server. I want to calculate the % of time my service was not working fine (meaning this TS was > 0). How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

For any query that produces continuous output of value 0 or 1 you can count an average over time using function of [`avg_over_time`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time), like this:

```
avg_over_time( (<your_query>) [range:resolution] )
```

Where `range` is time range over which you want to calculate average, and `resolution` is how often sample of your query should be evaluated within range.
`resolution` can also be omitted (without omitting `:`). In that case global evaluation interval (`evaluation_interval` from config, by default `1m`) will be used as a default value.

Since your query produces values other then 1, that for intents of this exercise should be treated as 1, it can be modified by adding `> bool 0`. It uses [boolean comparison](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) to convert all values that satisfy the condition into 1.

So final query would be

```
avg_over_time(
 (
  sum(
   ALERTS{alertname="IngestionStopped", alertstate="firing"}
   unless on(table) (
     ALERTS{alertname="MyAlert1", alertstate="firing"}
     or ALERTS{alertname="MyAlert2", alertstate="firing"})
   or vector(0))
   > bool 0
 )
 [30d:1m] 
)
```

Adjust resolution according to your situation, but remember that alert rules are evaluated (and subsequently metric `ALERTS` updated) only once every `evaluation_interval`, so no need to go crazy low there.

Demo of similar query can be seen [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=%23%20when%20targets%20were%20unavailable%0Aup%20!%3D%201&g0.tab=0&g0.display_mode=lines&g0.show_exemplars=0&g0.range_input=30d&g1.expr=%23%20percentage%20of%20time%20when%20at%20least%20one%20target%20was%20unavailable%0Aavg_over_time(%0A%20(%0A%20%20sum(up%20!%3D%20bool%201%20or%20vector(0))%0A%20%20%20%3E%20bool%200%0A%20)%0A%20%5B30d%3A1m%5D%20%0A)&g1.tab=1&g1.display_mode=lines&g1.show_exemplars=0&g1.range_input=1h).